# How to update selected checkbox values in php mysql?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

In html table selected checkbox when submit, update selected checkbox values to mysql database

example : `update enquires set status = '2' where id in ( selected checkbox values)`

[check box screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHxWI.jpg)
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHxWI.jpg)

Comment: Can you make an example on source code please ?

Comment: Give name to checkbox and give vale you post it and take it as $_POST[“name”]

Comment: @deoncagadoes uploaded screenshot

Comment: Can you put database structure of **enquires** and **checkbox** ?

Comment: @deoncagadoes added database schema

Comment: And **checkbox** database schema ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the name attr of checkbox as array like 'id[]'

like.

```
<form method="post">
<table>
<tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row_id;?>" name="id[]"></td>
        <!-- other table data <td> -->
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row_id;?>" name="id[]"></td>
        <!-- other table data <td> -->
    </tr>


</table>

<input type="submit" name="update_data" value="update">
</form>
```

After submit the form you will get all the checked id in array. using implode get the id separated by comma and use in update query.

like.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['update_data'])){
    echo $query_id = implode(',', $_POST['id']);

    //write the update query
}
?>
```

Comment: @Manjunath V M,If this ans is helpful and working as expected, Please mark this ans :)